# Will Collision monitor be backported to Humble?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I just saw a [pull](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/pull/2982) request of **Collision monitor** on Nav2. It seems from docs that it will be supported from next ROS release (Iron).

I was wondering **if it will be backported to Humble**. This feature looks very attractive and will be very helpful.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403900/will-collision-monitor-be-backported-to-humble?/) by [jainr](https://answers.ros.org/users/92132/jainr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2022-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it will be backported.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0